# Calling a function is not getting executed

Tags: r

I wrote a function that calculates the distance between 2 vectors. And below is its code.

```
myfu <- function(a=c(a,b),b=c(c,d))
{
res <- sqrt((d^2-b^2)-(c^2-a^2))
return(res)}
```

But when I call values for the function it is throwing an error. Please guide me what wrong I am doing here.

```
myfu(x=c(1,2),y=c(5,8))
Error in myfu(x = c(1, 2), y = c(5, 8)) : object 'd' not found
```

Comment: Why are you calling the function with parameters x, y when they are defined as a, b? The code in your question generates a different error to the error in the question. Apart from that, I think `myfu <- function(a, b, c, d) { ... }` will solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say `a=c(a,b), b = c(c,d)`, you're giving default values to your two arguments. Your function only knows `a` and `b`, and not the default arguments you have provided. I think @neilfws's answer will work, or you could also index `a` and `b` like this:

```
myfu <- function(a, b){
  # check a and b length
  if (length(a) !=2 & length(b) != 2)
    return(NA)
  res <- sqrt((b[2]^2-a[2]^2)-(b[1]^2-a[1]^2))
  return(res)}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass arguments as vectors, you can use

```
myfu1 <- function(a, b) {
      sqrt(diff((b^2 - a^2)))
}

myfu1(c(1, 2), c(5, 8))
#[1] 6

myfu1(c(1, 2), c(6, 8))
#[1] 5
```